# Gitlab CI how to ignore directory using rules syntax?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was able to ignore directory, file changes using the following syntax.

```
build:
  script: npm run build
  except:
    changes:
      - "*.md"
      - "src/**/*.ts"
```

With this configuration `build` job is going to run except git changes include only `*.md` extension file or `*.ts` files in `src` directory. They're ignored.

But then they deprecated this `only:changes`, `except:changes` syntax and warned to use `rules` syntax instead. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find how to ignore directory, file changes using this new syntax.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on [documents of `rules: changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), it seems `when: never` must be used with `rules: changes` syntax. Like the following:

```
build:
  script: npm run build
  rules:
    - changes:
      - "*.md"
      - "src/**/*.ts"
      when: never

    - when: always
```

If changed paths in the repository match above regular expressions then the job will not be added to any pipeline. In other cases the job always will be run by pipelines.

Comment: `build` job isn't triggered when other files, directories changed.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my answer. I had forgotten line `when: always`.

Comment: Nice thanks for the edit. It looks like it's working as expected. Never knew there could be multiple `when` condition. I should've noted that there was an another job that's supposed to run only this `src` directory change. That job is working as expected when commit changes include only that directory. But when commit changes include changes to both root dir & src dir, this `build` job isn't running. Unfortunately I think it was same when I was using old syntax. If you think this problem is solvable please let me know.

Comment: Glad to help!! I'll think about what you commented on.

Comment: Do you have a solution for the problem? I don't want to run the build when my merge request only contains `.md` changes, but when it contains `.md` changes + some other changes it should build.

Comment: I created a gitlab issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/301070

Comment: Don't know if `when: always` is intentional, the default should be `when: on_success`, otherwise the job will run even if previous steps fail

Comment: Note that this is not really a regular expression. Here the full supported syntax: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/File.html#method-c-fnmatch

Answer (score 14):

Surprisingly enough, it seems that is currently not possible - neither with `except/only`, nor with `rules`. This seems to be the "best" open issue for this requested feature: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/198688

I guess you could only reverse the logic and enable the build when a relevant change has been detected (sample adapted from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges ):

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - relevant/path/file
      when: on_success
    - changes:
        - path/to/config/file
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: Thanks for the research. The reversed logic does not really work when having overlapping globs for files to include and files to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse the brief answer, but I've just had some success with using the unix glob 'not syntax', ie:

```
    - changes:
      - '[^d][^o][^c][^s]**/**/*'
      - '*' # above matcher does not match files in base folder
```

This matches changes to all files not in ./docs/ , and seems to correctly trigger the step for any changes outside that folder, but not for chages within that folder.

edit2: This actually matches each character individually.  So will also ignore a folder called `licensing`, as there's a rejected match on the third character (`c`). `'[^d][^o]**/**/*'` is currently doing the job for us, but ymmv.

As a result, other matching rules within the "rules" property will still trigger the job.  My whole rules statement needed to be set up to *not* trigger the job on any other rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH     # Run for merges
      when: never
      variables:
        BUILD_ENVIRONMENT: "production"
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID                          # Run for merge requests
      when: never
      variables:
        BUILD_ENVIRONMENT: "staging"
    - changes:
      - '[^d][^o][^c][^s]**/**/*'
      - '*'
```

This isn't well tested yet though!

edit:fixed a little, with inspiration from Jan Spets:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/32673

and the gitLab source code for the Changes feature:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/build/rules/rule/clause/changes.rb