# Gitlab only and except not working simultaneously

Tags: gitlab

I have written a Git pipeline `gitlab.yaml`, where I am having both `except` and `only` rules.

I have a `design/` folder which I am ignoring for most of the jobs and, except this folder, all my pipeline should get executed.

```yaml
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  except:
    changes:
      - design/*
```

But: when I make changes to design folder file, *and* other files, then all the jobs are not getting executed.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve]. Also, there are two variants for these rules, an old and a new one, and they don't get along well with each other. Carefully read the docs!

Answer (score 1):

Note: depending on your GitLab version (or with `gitlab.com`), you need to rewrite your exclusion rules using `rules:`

See "[Transitioning your `only`/`except` syntax to `rules`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/5a30bcfe8c90c3eb23a19e88aa69b9b102879e06/doc/user/application_security/index.md#transitioning-your-onlyexcept-syntax-to-rules)".
The question "[Gitlab CI how to ignore directory using rules syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62689235/6309)".

However, as illustrated with [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 301070](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/301070), this new syntax does not solve your issue.

> Currently it seems not to be possible to use rules:changes: to trigger a job when certain globs match, ignoring other sets of globs.

So for now, this is still being discussed/fixed.

You can try this [glob pattern](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%5B%21design%5D%2A%2F%2A%2A&matches=false&tests=project-a%2Ftest%2Ftest.txt&tests=project-a%2Ftest%2Ftest.md&tests=a%2Fproject-a%2F%2Ftest.md&tests=design%2Fs):

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      changes:
        - '[!design]*/**'
```